# nodejs static content NOT using sendFile

Tags: node.js

How can I make nodejs serve up static content without having to use sendFile? The problem with sendFile is it opens another tab as you navigate from page to page, here is a snippet...

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.post('/verify', function(request, response) {
  var oneTimeCode = request.body.oneTimeCode;
  var timeEntry = Date.now();
  if (oneTimeCode == 'abc123') {      
    response.sendFile('/home/ubuntu/form.html');
  } else {......
```

Can I use something like this in place of sendFile?

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/home/ubuntu/form.html'));
```

Comment: Depends on how exactly you want to be able to access it. Drop `form.html` from your snippet and then you'll be able to access it from `//domain.com/form.html`, **along with anything else in that folder.** sendFile shouldn't be opening a new tab though.. that effectively makes this an XY problem.

Comment: so are you saying it would look like this? `response.sendFile('//https://domain.com/form.html');`

Comment: no.... //domain.com/form.html is client side how you would access it. You would do a redirect in node to get to it from the verify route. note however that none of this will fix your primary concern of *"The problem with sendFile is it opens another tab as you navigate from page to page"* because sendFile doesn't do that. Therefore, whatever is doing it will continue to do it no matter what solution you implement server-side.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`express.static` is not a good option to serve an individual file.
 It is intended to serve all static assets inside a folder using the url for file name resolution as described [here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.static).

`sendFile()` shouldn't be responsible for opening new tabs. May be you have a wrong target on the anchor html element?

If you want to send static content without using `sendFile()` you can always open the static asset file and transfer the content over the response stream. This is what `sendFile()` does. You can review the [source code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L385) and take ideas from there.

Comment: I see you have marked this as the answer. Could you describe the root cause of your problem for future references?

Comment: I suppose this best answers my original question:    `express.static is not a good option to serve an individual file. It is intended to serve all static assets inside a folder using the url for file name resolution as described here.` although I still have multiple tabs opening and I'm not sure exactly how else to proceed.